# Renewal of passport before visa stamping request

Tags: visas, canada, passport-renewals

I was asked to submit my passport for visa stamping, but I had to renew my passport to add my spouses name. I have received the new passport now. Will there be any issues if I submit my new passport, instead of my old passport which was  listed when the application was submitted?